# Cannot read property length of undefined in passing arrays as options for multi select box in Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am getting `length` of undefined error in Javascript.

I have an ajax `post` function upon `select tag` change

index.html.erb:

```
<%= select_tag :team_id, options_from_collection_for_select(Team.where(campus_id:current_user.campus_id).order('name'), 'id', 'name'), class:"team-selection-workouts", prompt:"Select" %>
```

change function in workout.js.coffee:

```
$(".team-selection-workouts").change ->
    $.post "/workouts/filter_by_team",
    team_id: $(".team-selection-workouts").val()
```

routes.rb

```
resources :workouts do
    collection do
      post :filter_by_team
    end
end
```

controller action in `workouts_controller.rb`

So I passed `team_id` value using ajax from the coffeescript above.

```
def filter_by_team
    # For Trainers
    @team = Team.find(params[:team_id])
    @workouts = Workout.find(:all, order: 'name', :conditions => ['team_id = ? and status = ?', @team.id, 'new'])
  end
```

In my filter_by_team.js.erb:

I passed `@workouts` object for the partial

```
$('#team-workouts').html("<%=j render :partial => 'workouts/filtered_by_team', locals: {workouts: @workouts}%>");
```

Every select box `change()` the partial must be rendered according to the `team_id`

_filtered_by_team.html.erb:

Now passing locals `workouts` to the partial file... I have a multi select box...

```
<%= select_tag :workout, options_from_collection_for_select(workouts, "id", "name"), size: 7, class: 'excercises_muliti_select' %>
```

First `select()` change works but upon choosing another option from the select box, I'm getting the `length` jquery error.

To be exact:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined jquery.js?body=1:606
jQuery.extend.each jquery.js?body=1:606
(anonymous function) jqBootstrapValidation.js?body=1:459
jQuery.extend.each jquery.js?body=1:632
jQuery.fn.jQuery.each jquery.js?body=1:254
(anonymous function) jqBootstrapValidation.js?body=1:457
jQuery.event.dispatch jquery.js?body=1:3046
elemData.handle
```

So, because of this the `post` request is stopping. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Please post the code surrounding line 606 of `jquery.js`.

Comment: Hi, please see http://d.pr/i/QWei for the line 606

Comment: Is this just a warning, I got the select box working now, but warnings in the console are annoying.

Comment: I think this is probably a fatal error, in JavaScript at least. You aren't passing an `obj` into your function. What is the function call?

Comment: It's a `change` function for a select box

Answer (score 0):

You're receiving this jQuery because you're not sending an `obj` to your `change()` function. Try sending the *selected* option value to your action in AJAX:

```
# workout.js.coffee
$(".team-selection-workouts").change ->
    $.post "/workouts/filter_by_team",
    team_id: $(".team-selection-workouts :selected").val() # notice the `:selected` pseudo-selector
```